# What are the key differences between Brihaspatiniti and Sukraniti?

Tags: schools, nitishastra

Niti sastra mainly deals with the duties of the King: how he should treat his subjects, how he should treat his enemy, how he should run the kingdom etc.

In ancient India, there were two schools of Niti sastras: Brihaspatiniti and Sukraniti. Different Nitivids used to follow either of these two schools. For example, Kanika in Mahabharata was a follower of Sukraniti (Nrisinghaprasad Bhaduri, commentary on Mahabharata: Katha Amritasaman).

There must be some fundamental differences between these two schools. What are the key differences between these two schools?